# How to creat a Human Design Chart in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

[image]

How Can I draw Human Design Chart as shown in Image. I have all the coordinates of it now I do not know how to draw it in android. As there are too many coordinates of each total 64 lines and  triangles how can I draw it
I have all the coordinates in csv files.

Please Help. I am searching for it for too long I do not know how to do.

Comment: Canvas is probably what you want... but this is overly broad. Because I'm not 'entirely' sure that is even what you want...

Comment: I want these lines and triangle how can I show them ? @mawalker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simply Import all your Coordinates in Database or .csv file and use this method**

```
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        Path path = new Path();

            path.moveTo(x,y);
            path.lineTo(x,y);
            path.close();
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the chart in SVG and use something like this [SVG-Android](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android) to render it to the Android canvas.
You could create the SVG with Photoshop and the like. Then use it like this:

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.svg);
Picture picture = svg.getPicture();
Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
```

Comment: but it's values will  be changed at run time. How can I do that.like after some calculation the lines and triangles will be colored

Comment: That would be a good requirement to specify in your original question. The library I posted does support color substitution but only upon load. ` SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android, 0xFF9FBF3B, 0xFF1756c9);` So you could switch a color after a calculation. But only one, maybe there are other libraries that support dynamic color substitution.

Comment: Thank You @niels I will try it and revert back to you